# Difference between chained and batch element queries?

Tags: query, elementquery

I apologize if this has been asked or addressed already, but I have a question concerning Element Queries. The docs show two possible ways:

Chained Methods

```
{% set query = craft.entries()
    .section('news')
    .limit(10) %}
```

Batch-set Parameters

```
{% set query = craft.entries({
    section: 'news',
    limit: 10
}) %}
```

**The examples shown above (from the docs) obviously accomplish the exact same thing--but what is the difference, if any?**

It is my assumption that the batch-set way of querying elements allows for more options, is that true? And does either way have an effect on performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### general

The first way creates an object of type `EntryQuery`, you then call the 2 **functions** `section` and `limit`

In PHP you would do the following:

```
$query = Entry::find()->section('news')->limit(10);
```

The second creates an array `section => 'news', 'limit' => 10` you then call `Yii2::configure($query, $array)` with your `EntryQuery` which does:

```
public static function configure($object, $properties)
{
    foreach ($properties as $name => $value) {
        $object->$name = $value;
    }

    return $object;
}
```

Thus you **don't** call functions but define the **properties** directly. In PHP it would look like

```
$query = Entry::find();
Craft::configure($query, ['section' => 'news', 'limit' => 10]);
```

#### Performance

Because of the above it's **important** what you do. The first way calls **functions** the second way calls **properties**.

As for your comparison the first way is a little bit faster because you didn't attach functions that requires the use of `magic methods` => `__call` (in the `ElementQueryBehavior`) as soon as you search/filter for custom fields the `Craft::configure` way will always be a little bit faster because it can set the values directly instead of using the resource heavy [__call](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods) function

For example:

```
// faster
$query = Entry::find()
    ->section('news')
    ->limit(10)

// slower
$query = Entry::find();
Craft::configure($query, [
    'section' => 'news', 
    'limit' => 10
]);
```

Against

```
// slower
$query = Entry::find()
    ->section('news')
    ->limit(10)
    ->multiselect('test')
    ->subline('foo');

// faster
$query = Entry::find();
Craft::configure($query, [
    'section' => 'news',
    'limit' => 10,
    'multiselect' => 'test',
    'subline' => 'foo'
]);
```

#### Conclusion

Keep in mind when I say "slower" or "faster" I'm talking about a few milliseconds (when I run the last example 1000 times its 511ms vs 497ms) so in the end it does not really matter. If it's really important in terms of speed: as soon as you use the `__call` method because you need to change properties in the `ElementQueryBehavior` you would prefer to use `Craft::configure`.

Besides that: there is absolutely no difference between those two.. There are no hidden "benefits" you don't have more options, you can't do something "better"